# How to connect apache jean fuseki remote database using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, fuseki

I am new to apache jean fuseki database

Could you please direct me how to connect apache jena fuseki database using JDBC(org.apache.jena.jdbc.remote.RemoteEndpointDriver)

Is there any way to connect using JDBC

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not using pure JDBC.
From the [documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/) your options are to use RDFConnection or the SPARQL over JDBC library (linked to on the RDFConnection page). Alternatively you just treat the endpoint as a web service passing the SPARQL as a query parameter etc.